# Making nested maps with @each in SASS

Tags: sass

I have the following SASS working fine, which I'm using to try and make media query changes DRYer than they are for me right now. Aiming for some modularity or summat.

```
$perfect-fourth: 1.3333333333333;

$ma-base: 16;
$grandma-base: 18;

$type-ratio: $perfect-fourth;

$font-sizes: (
    ma: (
        xsmall: round($ma-base/$type-ratio),
        small: round($ma-base),
        medium: round($ma-base*$type-ratio),
        large: round($ma-base*$type-ratio*$type-ratio),
        xlarge: round($ma-base*$type-ratio*$type-ratio*$type-ratio)
    ),
    grandma: (
        xsmall: round($grandma-base/$type-ratio),
        small: round($grandma-base),
        medium: round($grandma-base*$type-ratio),
        large: round($grandma-base*$type-ratio*$type-ratio),
        xlarge: round($grandma-base*$type-ratio*$type-ratio*$type-ratio)
    )
    // With several more lists
);

@function size($size, $family-member:ma) {
    @return map-get(map-get($font-sizes, $family-member), $size);
}
```

The idea is that I'll be calling, for instance:

```
// 'rem' and 'media' are functions I have defined elsewhere
@include media($ma) {
  p { font-size: rem(size(medium));
}
@include media($grandma) {
  p { font-size: rem(size(medium, grandma));
}
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to generate those nested maps and put them inside of $sizes. Here's what I have right now:

```
$family-sizes: (grandkid:14, kid:16, ma:16, grandma:18);

$font-sizes : (
    @each $family-member, $size in $family-sizes {
        $family-member: (
            xsmall: round($size/$family-ratio),
            small: round($size),
            medium: round($size*$family-ratio),
            large: round($size*$family-ratio*$family-ratio),
            xlarge: round($size*$family-ratio*$family-ratio*$family-ratio)  
        )
    };
);

@function size($size, $family-member:ma) {
    @return map-get(map-get($font-sizes, $family-member), $size);
}
```

This, sadly, isn't working, and none of the other methods I've tried have worked. The @each directive seems to be working, but I'm stuck on putting those lists inside of a single list. Any tips or ideas? I'm thinking that map-merge might help, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `@each` (or any directive really) does not return a value, so there's nothing to store into a variable.  You need to use a function that works on mappings (or lists) to programatically append the mappings, just like you would if you were working with ordinary lists:

```
$font-sizes: ();
@each $family-member, $size in $family-sizes {
    $font-sizes: map-merge($font-sizes, ($family-member: (
        xsmall: round($size/$family-ratio),
        small: round($size),
        medium: round($size*$family-ratio),
        large: round($size*$family-ratio*$family-ratio),
        xlarge: round($size*$family-ratio*$family-ratio*$family-ratio)  
    )));
}
```

Now, if you're looking for a simpler way of going about this, I would recommend taking advantage of the [Modular Scale](https://github.com/Team-Sass/modular-scale) library.

```
@import "modular-scale";

$font-base: 16px !default;
$font-scale: 1.5 !default;
// shouldn't need to modify these
$font-keywords: (xsmall: -2, small: -1, medium: 0, large: 1, xlarge: 2);
$fractional-units: em, rem, unquote('%'); // add as needed

@function size($keyword, $base: $font-base, $scale: $font-scale) {
  $size: ms(map-get($font-keywords, $keyword), $base, $scale);
  @return if(index($fractional-units, unit($base)), $size, round($size));
}

.foo {
  a: size(medium);
  b: size(small);
  c: size(large, 1em);
  d: size(xlarge, 1em);
  f: size(xsmall, size(small));
}
```

http://sassmeister.com/gist/45c07f9aa6b2daa984be

Comment: Jumping back and forth between JS and abstracted SASS is causing some issues for me, apparently. This answer works great; the part that was throwing me off (it seems really obvious now, though?) was figuring out how to nest that second map inside of the map-merge call.

Anyone know of any documentation on abstracted Sass that doesn't just list specific solutions to specific problems? I've been writing with Sass for a while, now, and was still (albeit, tiredly) surprised last night to find that usage of @each wasn't working.

Comment: It is through understanding specific examples that we learn to recognize abstract patterns.  If you have a more specific question, you're always free to ask another.  If you're just looking for inspiration, you might try browsing [Sache](http://www.sache.in/)

Comment: Sache is a great resource, to be sure -- I'm still hoping to find some collation of design patterns in Sass, as has been done with JS, a la [this](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/). Pretty sure nothing like this exists as of now? Anyways, thanks for your help.

Comment: I've added an alternate solution, which is considerably more elegant than dynamically generating mappings.

Comment: I like the approach! Though I'm not using Compass (in favor of a congery of bourbon + neat + scut + some handwritten stuff), this is still very instructional code. Cheers! Would vote up if I could yet.